# Send notifications using fire base from a Dot Net Web API to Blazor wasm

Tags: .net, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, blazor

I am trying to send a notification using firebase from a dot net web api app to a blazor web assembly app.

Problem is that when I call the API and pass for it the FCM Registeration token from swagger notifications are being send appears successfully,

but when calling the same API and passing for it the same FCM registeration token the API succeed but the notification doesn't appear.

here is a sample of my code

**note that I am using FirebaseAdmin Package in dot net to handle this**

Service

```
   private async Task SendFcmMessageAsync(string token, string title, string body)
{
    var message = new Message()
    {
        Token = token,
        Notification = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification()
        {
            Title = title,
            Body = body
        }
    };

    await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
}
```

API

```
 [HttpPost("Send")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendNotification(FireBaseMessageModel fireBaseMessageModel)
    {
        await SendFcmMessageAsync(fireBaseMessageModel.Token, fireBaseMessageModel.Title, fireBaseMessageModel.Body);
        return Ok(new ApiResponse(200, "Success notify"));
    }
```

Model

```
public class FireBaseMessageModel
{
    public string Token { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

here is what happens when I call the API from swagger or even postman

[calling the API from Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u8ne.png)

and here is what happens when I call the same API from the blazor App (which contains the code that gets the FCM token)

[calling the API from Blazor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAv6d.png)

Here is the JS code in the index.html that gets the FCM registeration token

```
   <!--FCM TOKEN-->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

    <script>

        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIz**********SECRET****************",
            authDomain: "**********SECRET****************",
            projectId: "**********SECRET****************",
            storageBucket: "**********SECRET****************",
            messagingSenderId: "**********SECRET****************",
            appId: "**********SECRET****************",
            measurementId: "**********SECRET****************"
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging.requestPermission()
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Notification permission granted.");
                return messaging.getToken();
            })
            .then((token) => {
                console.log("FCM Token:", token);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error requesting permission:", error);
            });

        // Function to retrieve the FCM registration token
        function getFCMToken() {
            return firebase.messaging().getToken().then(function (token) {
                return token;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error('Error getting FCM token:', error);
                return null;
            });
        }
    </script>
    <!--End FCM TOKEN-->
```